# Arduino internet data disappear after 10 seconds

Tags: http, arduino, get

I am new with Arduino, today I tried to connect to WiFi with my TTGO board and GET data from URL. It connects to WiFi properly, GET data from URL, but after 10 seconds all data disappear.

I understand it happens because of **tft.fillScreen(TFT_GREY);** command, but I do not understand, why function not continue, after that command are other commands which are getting that data and also commands to print it.

My plan was to refresh data from URL every 10 seconds.

My code:

```
#include <TFT_eSPI.h> // Graphics and font library for ST7735 driver chip
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();  // Invoke library, pins defined in User_Setup.h

#define TFT_GREY 0x5AEB // New colour

const char* ssid = "MyNetwork";
const char* password =  "password";
int number = 10;



void setup(void) {
  tft.init();
  tft.setRotation(1);


  delay(4000);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    tft.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  tft.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
}

void loop() {
refreshData();
}

void refreshData ()
{
 
  
  // Fill screen with grey so we can see the effect of printing with and without 
  // a background colour defined
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_GREY);

  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { //Check the current connection status
 
    HTTPClient http;
 
    http.begin("http://example.com"); //Specify the URL
    int httpCode = http.GET();                                        //Make the request
 
    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
 
        String payload = http.getString();
        //tft.println(httpCode);
        tft.print(payload);


      }
 
    else {
      tft.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
   http.end(); //Free the resources
  }
 number ++;
  delay(10000); 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I did not realize was, that all new data goes out of display, so everytime it needed to set cursor at start by `tft.setCursor();`